# Why for a magnetic vector potential $A=\frac{1}{2}B \times r$ is $r$ measured from the $z$-axis, not from the origin?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, reference-frames, magnetic-moment

This is an extract from Feynman. He is looking for various expressions for A to give a uniform B field along the $z$-axis $B_0$

I have noticed that if we do take r to be the vector displacement from the origin against his wishes it still produces the correct B field. Or am I wrong?

[image: net]

This is what I have using r as the vector displacement from the origin and it seems correct to me.

[image]

Comment: Third solution of what? This question cannot currently be understood without access to the Feynman book.

Comment: The solution for an expression of A for a uniform B field along the z axis

Comment: When a question is unclear, you should clarify it by editing, not by replying in comments.

Comment: I’ve edited it thanks

Comment: Please don’t post images of handwritten math. Or images of textbooks.

Comment: I’m trying to clarify the question like you said

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Without knowing, what the "third solution" is. I just can show you the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2TG9.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible Feynman was just trying to show that this equation works for r’ (the vector measured just from the z axis) in this special case of Bx=By=0 and that the general formula for all cases uses r (the vector displacement from the origin). We can only use r’ in this special case since z only appears in the usual case when multiplied by Bx or By so if they are both 0 then z can take any value without affecting A.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\vec{B} = B_0 \hat{k}$, the difference between $\vec{B} \times \vec{r}$ and $\vec{B} \times \vec{r}'$ is
$$
\vec{B} \times \vec{r} - \vec{B} \times \vec{r}' = \vec{B} \times (\vec{r} - \vec{r}') = \vec{B} \times (z \hat{k}) = 0.
$$
In other words, $\vec{B} \times \vec{r} =\vec{B} \times \vec{r}'$, and both methods lead to the same $\vec{A}$.